# Grouping results together and counting outcomes

Tags: php, html

I have pulled some data from my database and have output the following

```
20f -Won:0 Placed:0 
20f -Won:0 Placed:0 
20f -Won:0 Placed:0 
20f -Won:0 Placed:0 
20f -Won:0 Placed:0 
20f -Won:0 Placed:0 
20f -Won:1 Placed:1 
20f -Won:1 Placed:1 
20f -Won:0 Placed:0 
21.5f -Won:1 Placed:1 
21.5f -Won:0 Placed:0 
21.5f -Won:0 Placed:1 
21.5f -Won:0 Placed:1 
21.5f -Won:0 Placed:1 
21f -Won:0 Placed:1 
21f -Won:0 Placed:0 
22f -Won:0 Placed:0 
22f -Won:0 Placed:0 
22f -Won:0 Placed:0 
23f -Won:0 Placed:0 
23f -Won:0 Placed:0 
23f -Won:0 Placed:0 
24f -Won:0 Placed:0 
24f -Won:0 Placed:1
```

this has been done by using the following outcome

```
  $data .= .$Horsedist. " -Won:".$wintotals. " Placed:".$placetotals." <br />";
```

What i want to do is group each distance up and add the won and placed number so it would output the following (Raced been the total of the number)

```
20f -Won:2 Placed:2 Raced:9
21.5f -Won:1 Placed:4 Raced:5
21f -Won:0 Placed:1 Raced:2
22f -Won:0 Placed:0 Raced:3
23f -Won:0 Placed:0 Raced:3
24f -Won:0 Placed:1  Raced:2
```

I am struggling to figure how to do this. Below if a trimmed down version of the code

```
   <?php //pulling the data from database for the horse
         $sqlhorses = "SELECT distance,Place,Runners FROM  `horsesrp`  WHERE  `Horse` = '".$horse."' order by distance";
            $horseplaced = mysqli_query($db, $sqlhorses);
            $data = "";


        while($pasthorse = mysqli_fetch_array($horseplaced)){
        // setting wins and places to 0
        $placetotals = 0;
        $wintotals = 0;

        //pull where the horse places
        $placeddata = intval($pasthorse['Place']); 

    //if it finished first add one for win and one for placed
        if ($placeddata == 1)
        {
        $placetotals = 1;
        $wintotals =  1;
        }
        else
        {


        // if the were between 4 and 7 runners only award a place if it came 2nd
        if ($pasthorse['Runners'] > 4 and $pasthorse['Runners'] < 8 )
        {

        if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2)
        {
        $placetotals = 1;
        }
        }
        // if there are between 8 and 15 runners award a place for 2nd and 3rd
        if ($pasthorse['Runners'] > 7 and $pasthorse['Runners']< 16 )
        {
        if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 3  )
        {

        $placetotals = 1;
        }
        }
        //above 15 runners and award place for 2nd 3rd and 4th
        if ($pasthorse['Runners'] > 15  )
        {

        if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 3 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 4 )
        {
        $placetotals = 1;
        }
        }
        }


    // add it to a row to show the distance it ran and if it won or placed
          $data .= "<span style='font-size:10.5px'>".$Horsedist. " -Won:".$wintotals. " Placed:".$placetotals."  </span><br />";
        }

          }

        //now display it

        echo "<tr><td  >";
        echo "<td >".$data."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Comment: Hi ! Could it be possible to see the shape of the table(s) you're retrieving those data from?

Comment: Hey - im not pulling this data from tables - Wintotals and Place totals are worked out via code

Comment: $Horsedist only appears when displayed. Where is it defined ? What is it? Do $wintotals means that the horse finished first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh ok so it's not very difficult and you did most of the job.

The first way you could make it work according to your will would be to store those pieces of data in a temporary array and to aggregate results belonging to same subjects, e.g

```
$storage = array();

//Do what you want to do
// while(....) {

//and now, each iteration :
//If there isn't any entry for the current subject
if (!isset($storage[$Horsedist])) {
   $storage[$Horsedist] = array("win" => 0, "placed" => 0, "raced" => 0);
}

//Then increment if required
$storage[$Horsedist]["win"] += $wintotals;
$storage[$Horsedist]["placed"] += $placetotals;
$storage[$Horsedist]["raced"] += 1;

// }
//At the end of your loop, just display everything

$data = "";
foreach ($storage as $pony => $tab) {
   $data .= $pony. " -Won:".$tab["win"]. " Placed:".$tab["placed"]." Raced:".$tab["raced"]."<br />";
}

//Do whatever you want with $data
echo $data;
```

To be able to get details for a bunch of data, you have to track them at each iteration (because you can't simply to it at the very end, it's like wanting to know who has eaten how many sweets without knowing who picked in the bag and how often did they went for it). In the code above, I did assume you were using a loop to compute all your information (win, placed) and I just added the behavior above that would, for each iteration, check if the current $Horsedist has already registered information about itself. If it doesn't, then he declare its own "workspace". Then, it just add what you need to the global workspace. At the very end, the foreach loop is meant to display every "aggregated" detail (outside the loop)

I hope this helped, feel free to ask anything

Comment: Little confused with this.... how would i add it to here : }

  $data .= "<span style='font-size:10.5px'>".$Horsedist. " -Won:".$wintotals. " Placed:".$placetotals."  </span><br />";
}

Comment: Could you show us your entire code where this part is processed ? I'm not sure to understand your question

Comment: i have added above and trimmed it down to the need be stuff

Comment: Perfect - thanks for your time and explanation :) - im now off to buy some sweets :P